# Use gdb to debug assembly, how to skip a call

Tags: gdb

I'm debugging assembly code. I use stepi, but it would go into callees. How to skip the call instructions as using "n" when source code is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple: `nexti` is to `stepi` as `next` is to `step`