# How to skip (not execute!) a call in GDB when debugging without symbols?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, 64-bit

I am debugging a Linux program to which I have no symbols. The binary is stripped. No big deal, I can handle that. However, how can I skip a call inside the debugger when I reach a particular piece of code?

What I am asking is *not* this: [Use gdb to debug assembly, how to skip a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202860/use-gdb-to-debug-assembly-how-to-skip-a-call)

I am interested if I have a:

```
 call 0x12345678
 ...
```

to jump to the `...` straight **without *executing* the `call`**.

How can I do that?

Comment: but a breakpoint at the instruction just after that `call 0x12345678`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more reading I found the solution.

In my case I know the opcode for the `call` is fives bytes long, so I can resolve it by setting the [GDB register name](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html#Registers) `$pc` ("program counter") to jump over it:

```
set $pc+=5
```

According to the comment on this answer by [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50617/employed-russian) the following provides the same functionality:

```
jump *$pc+5
```

Assuming you have the `call` *at* address `0x01234567` and want to skip five bytes, you can do the following in your `.gdbinit`:

```
b *0x01234567
commands 1
x/i $pc
echo Not executing the call\n
set $pc+=5
x/i $pc
end
```

Comment: @EmployedRussian: thanks a bunch. Will edit this into my answer if you don't mind. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Set the `rip` value to the address of the instruction right after this `call 0x12345678`.